# Given an array of n points, the distance between two points is defined as min(abs(x1-x2), abs(y1-y2)) . find kth minimum distance

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I had solved this using max priority queue. What I did is that I keep inserting distance by iterating for all possible pairs until its size become k. And then if I found current distance greater than max-heap top I pop max-heap and insert this distance. Then after iterating for all possible pairs, the max-heap top would be our answer. The time complexity of this solution seems to be O(n^2 logn) and space complexity O(k). But I need to do better than this? What can be other approaches?

Following is the code snapshot:

```
int kthMin(vector<pair<int,int>> Points, int k) {
    priority_queue pq;

    for(int i=0;i<Points.size()-1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<Points.size(); j++) {
          int dist = min( abs(Points[i].first - Points[j].first), abs(Points[i].second - Points[j].second));
        if(pq.size()<k) pq.push(dist);
        else if(dist< pq.top()) {
          pq.pop();
          pq.push(dist);
        }
      }
    }
    return pq.top();
}
```

Comment: It seems like your question, if it had the code included, would be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you want to improve an existing (working) solution. In it's current state, it's not really suitable for any site on the SE network.

Comment: Sort all the x coordinates (remember to which point each coordinate belongs). Sort all the y coordinates likewise. Record all differences between *adjacent* coordinates (if this set of differences contains two differences that belong to the same pair of points, skip the larger one). Run quickselect on the resulting set of differences.

Comment: *"But I need to do better than this?"* - Do you? Why are you asking that? Do you have reason to believe you need to do better? Do you have size/time limits? Where is this problem from? Is it online somewhere with more details and testing?

Comment: If you follow brute force approach, find distance between all points, sort them, output k th min, it'll take O(n^2) time. If you want to improve complexity, then you can use binary search on distance

Comment: Find all distances (O(n^2)), then QuickSelect the Kth minimum (O(n)), so total complexity is O(n^2)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a faster approach.  How much faster is hard to say, my guess is probably something like `O(n^(3/2) log(n))`.

First stick all the points into a quadtree. Have each node in the quadtree contain as meta information the number of points in the rectangle, and the min and max for x and y.

And now your logic looks something like this.

```
lower = 0
upper = max(tree.max_x - tree.min_x, tree.max_y - tree.min_y)
while lower < upper:
    mid = (lower + upper) / 2
    max_below = lower
    min_above = upper
    count_below = 0
    count_at = 0
    stack = new stack
    stack.push((tree, tree)) # To order them, 
    while stack is not empty:
        # We want ordered "pairs of points of interest" meaning
        # p1 in tree1, p2 in tree2 and either p1.x < p2.x
        # or p1.x = p2.x and p1.y <= p2.y.
        (tree1, tree2) = stack.pop()
        if no pairs of points of interest (eg tree2.max_x < tree1.min_x):
            pass
        elsif all of tree1 within distance mid of all of tree2:
            count_below += tree1.count * tree2.count
            if max_below < max possible distance from tree1 to tree2:
                max_below = max possible distance from tree1 to tree2
        elsif all of tree1 at distance mid of all of tree2:
            count_at += tree1.count * tree2.count
        elsif all of tree1 more than distance mid of all of tree2:
            if min possible distance from tree1 to tree2 < min_above:
                min_above = min possible distance from tree1 to tree2
        elsif longest axis of tree1 longer than longest axis of tree2:
            for child of tree1:
                stack.push((child, tree2))
        else:
            for child of tree2:
                stack.push((tree1, child))

    if k < count_below:
        upper = max_below
    elsif k <= count_below + count_at:
        return mid
    else:
        lower = min_above
```

The idea being that your binary search "snaps" to one of the `O(n^2)` possible distances.  So after `O(log(n))` logarithmic number of searches, you'll find the right one.  And each search itself tries to count numbers in blocks whenever it can.  (Which the quadtree structure helps with.)

Good luck making this outline precise!